# WP задать PRIMARY KEY колонке при создании таблицы?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Почему при создании таблицы в WordPress не происходит назначение PRIMARY KEY для колонки

```
function create_table()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name}
                ( id INT NOT NULL default '0' AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  json LONGTEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
                  {$charset_collate}";
                dbDelta($sql);

                $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_name,
                    array(
                        'id' => 0,
                        'json' => 'test text',
                        'object_last_modified' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        create_table();
```

Не PRIMARY KEY, не AUTO_INCREMENT не назначаются. Подскажите, в чём синтаксическая ошибка?

Comment: Синтаксис wordpress мне не совсем знаком, но не забыли ли вы закрывающую скобку `)` в конце `sql-запроса`

Comment: нет, таблица создаеться, если убрать  'AUTO_INCREMENT' и 'PRIMARY KEY (`id`)' . Но мне как-раз они и нужны, поскольку без инкримента phpMyAdmin не дает возможности править таблицу

Comment: Измените `id INT NOT NULL default '0' AUTO_INCREMENT` на `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, и замените `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), PRIMARY KEY ('id')` на `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY ('id'))`.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.